Need help with current divider rule and transfer function in RLC circuit analysis

I have a question about the circuit analysis problem shown in the image.
I'm supposed to find the transfer function
H(s)  using the current divider rule
(CDR). Here's my approach so far, and I'm not sure if it's correct, so l'd appreciate some feedback. I got R1*R2/R1+R2+Zc as my answer.

Considering the central node, first apply the current divider formula. Then, given I1,  obtain Vo by Ohm's law:

